# How do I apply a border around a checkbox when checked?

Tags: html, css

I want to check a checkbox and apply a 1px border around it via an enclosing span tag.

I am a bit stuck on how to detect the checked css property and select the parent span to apply a property to the span?   Can I achieve this with only CSS? Below is what I have so far.

**CSS(Sass)**

```
input.checkbox
    opacity: 0

span.check
    width: 16px
    height: 16px
    border: 2px solid black
    display: inline-block
    position: relative

input.checkbox:checked  <--once i detect checked I am unsure how to apply the border to the parent span tag
    background: black
    position: absolute
    top: -8px
    left: 0px
```

**HTML**

```
<span class='check'><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="" /></span>
```

Comment: Your CSS needs `{}` and `;` unless you are using a new preprocessor...?

Comment: He uses Sass, as it mentioned `CSS(Sass)`

Comment: Oops my bad, I h8 preprocessors it's like polishing a turd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simply NO,

Cascading does not works like that way. You can't select `parent` in `CSS`. But yes you can do this by using sass/scss. But it will **not work as you expected**.

**It will just create a parent wrapper class. But it will not behave using the state of the child element. Because after compiling it's just `CSS`**

We might get a parent selector in the future, may be in CSS4. So we are keeping our fingers crossed. :)

e.g.

**SASS**

```
input.checkbox
    opacity: 0

span.check
    width: 16px
    height: 16px
    border: 2px solid black
    display: inline-block
    position: relative

input.checkbox:checked
    background: black
    position: absolute
    top: -8px
    left: 0px

    span.check &
        border: 2px solid black
```

**Output CSS,**

```
input.checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
}

span.check {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

input.checkbox:checked {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0px;
}
span.check input.checkbox:checked {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

---

### But You can achieve this by using CSS `siblings` selector,

**HTML,**

```
<label>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS,**

```
label {
   position: relative;
} 
input.checkbox {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

input.checkbox:checked + span.check {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/HA3bQ/167/

Answer (score 0):

No way to select a parent with CSS only (until CSS4), so you must use JS..

See this post that talking about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958).

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that done using CSS, only within the javascript wherever the checkbox resides.

Answer (score 0):

You can put some element after input

```
<label>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark></span>
</label>
```

And style with pseudo class `:checked`

```
.checkbox:checked ~ .checkmark {
  // There goes styles for custom checkmark
}
```

Recommend look at this [site](http://wtfforms.com/) for full examples

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is just use outline in css style

```css
input.checkbox:checked  {
 outline: 2px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<span class='check'><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="" /></span>
```